# dictionaryautocomplete does not work at all in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I entered this in user settings "auto_complete_selector": "source, text" but autocomplete does not launch.

I get this instead.

Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in C:\Users\shelly\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\DictionaryAutoComplete.sublime-settings:1:25

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you added this line outside of the braces.
You need to have it inside so something like
`{
   "auto_complete_selector": "source, text" 
}`